# How to sanitize HTML Input values before rendering on client side where we can filter allowed tags

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to sanitize my application from XSS attacks.
I am doing both at the server side and at the client side , 
My requirement is to allow some of the tags(like `<div>` etc). but for client side, I am not able to find a library which has this method/property of filtering the tags. Any suggestion would be helpful

Comment: So are u asking for a library?

Comment: If you do it server-side, why do you need to do it client-side? You should never rely on client-side code. Is it just to tell the user their input is invalid?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sanitize-html if you're doing node code looks promising. Library suggestions are kind of off topic for StackOverflow, though.

Comment: This is fairly dangerous if you don’t know what you’re doing. Usually you don’t Want to let users write arbitrary html that you will then render.. You have your own system like stack overflow has implemented.